# dotted lines are not showing up in CSS...!

Tags: css

I am just working on a site.Here got completed everything..but almost..one thing not getting..so thought you people might help me...

Here it is please :

Here i am trying to make the dotted lines just right below the links Like this :

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2f07uy8.jpg

Here is the above image given CSS code please :

```
.navigation li ul li a {
    color: #000;
    background: none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but it's not showing up right..Here is the current image:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/es5jrq.jpg

Here is the above image given CSS code please :

```
.navigation li ul li a {
    color: #000;
    background: #e4e4e4;
    height: 0; 
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the html as well. Maybe in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure...Here are live links to sites:
The Correct One : http://d3sign-mirage.com/universal/
The Incorrect One : http://huntedhunter.com/universal/

Comment: You have set `height:0`, this will hide your element potentially

Comment: Beside when I remove height:0; so a white lines starts to showing up right above the links..which I don't want..to show up..!

Comment: please post the HTML for the menu, and preferably a fiddle or codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use after class to draw a dotted line below the links and you can use letter spacing to space out the dots the way you like it.

```
.navigation li ul li a {
    color: #000;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation li ul li a:after {
    content: "...............................";
    color: #000;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Adjust the bottom value on the :after pasedo-class to suit your needs. Sometimes you wouldnt be able to see the line drawn by the :after pseudo class, so undo the Overflow hidden to figure out where the dotted line is.

===========================================================================================
fixes:

```
.navigation li ul li {
background: none;
padding: 12px 12px 6px;
float: none;
display: block;
}
.navigation li ul li a {
color: #000;
background: none !important;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
box-shadow: none;
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navigation li ul li a:after {
content: "..................................................";
color: #000;
position: absolute;
bottom: 3px;
left: 0;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

The white line was a box shadow. You need to optimize your site, it takes ages to load.

Comment: Bro..can you check please..I added that..and everything is messed up..!

Comment: have a look on the codepen I provided. Should help you understand how to implement it. If that doesnt work, copy the code of your menu on codepen and send me the link.

Comment: Bro...i tried...to copy code at codepen but that is not showing up there right...here is the live link bro..Have a look at this please : http://huntedhunter.com/universal/

Comment: I want to remove the white line which is showing right above the links and want the dotted line to be place right below the links..please

Comment: see the answer for the fixes you need

Comment: Infact you helped alot..but infact to tell you..that I make the code right the old one..very before..and then removed just the box-shadow right from the Josh Rutherford answer comments..and it worked..thanks..any way...I will select your answer...Bro..and you will get reputatation...

Comment: ramesh_anand. no worries buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `<a>`'s a fixed height, as opposed to `0`. Using 22px seems to work fine.

Comment: Sure..Bro..I tried this already..but when I give height:20px; so a white lines starts to showing up right above the links..which I don't want..to show up..!

Comment: This is due to the `box-shadow` on `ul.flyout li a, .nav-bar li ul li a`. If you remove that it looks fine here.

Comment: Bro..I am not getting any CSS code related to your given CSS code for box-shadow..? Can you please show me the exact code right out from the Style.css file..?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at both of the sites and after checking the incorrect one I came to some conclusions.

a. you have **way too much styling**. It's just cluttering up your code. The key word here is simplifying.

b. don't use `font`, it has become somewhat obsolete in the last years.

c. the white line above is because you're using `box-shadow` with offset of 1px (in foundation.css line 478). Do you need this attribute? if not, maybe you should remove it.

d. can't find any `border-bottom` style anywhere in the element.

Comment: Thanks..bro..for suggestions..next time..I will try to get rid of these old...codes..